# How can I get Skype-like shared history among all clients using Jabber?

Tags: skype, history, jabber, xmpp

Skype does this neat thing where it sends the same history (event log, message log) to all clients connected to that account. This results in exactly the same chat log on all clients, even containing your own messages in correct chronological order. I'd like that same effect using Jabber. How would that be possible?

Currently in Jabber, you don't receive your own messages on other clients and you also get messages from other people only for clients that are currently subscribed (many clients unsubscribe on inactivity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question is software independent, the generic answer is that [XEP-0136](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) defines server side message archiving procedures for Jabber. In theory your client software would have to enable message archiving with your server. The practical problem here is that I do not know of any server (nor client for that matter) that implements XEP-0136.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/271185/jabber-client-with-support-of-gtalk-xep-136